# iframe in xcode has a overflowing width when I embed a google doc

Tags: ios, css, xcode, iframe, google-docs

I have an xcode project with html files. I am embedding a google doc using an iframe, but when I run the simulator, the width overflows on the right for iphone 6 and larger. It looks fine on iphone 5.

I've tried to change the margins in google docs and attempted some styling of the iframe.

```css
iframe {
  width: 100%;
  display: block;
}
```

```html
<iframe src="thesrc"></iframe>
```

I have also tried to embed it a container, but that didn't work either. I'm not sure if it's a css issue or I can't get a responsive iframe within xcode. Again, seems to be working fine on iphone 5.

Answer (score 0):

If I understood your question correctly, I think you need to provide the correct media CSS rules. I don't know though if you can this in the external html of an iframe.

to perform media queries, you can do something like

```
@media screen and (min-width:500px) {
  body {
    margin: 0 auto;
    width: 768px;
  }
}
```

Comment: Can you elaborate please on how I would do that? Using a meta tag?

Comment: this is in a native iOS project. Not a responsive webpage.

Comment: Correct. But using media queries detects the size of your browser. In this case there is no browser?

Comment: We are talking about html files, so there is a browser. Where is the doc displayed?

Comment: Within an iphone app.